# Magento 2.4.2: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')

Tags: magento2, javascript, frontend, undefined, adobe-commerce

In the payment page of our Magento store did I notice the following error, and I'm not sure if it can be ignore because it is not in red

[image]